# How can I get javascript code of website?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I tried going to inspect and then source but most of the websites use bundler like webpack so JavaScript code is not understandable, is there any way to unpack all the modules from the main.js? I tried DE bundle npm package but it did not work.

Comment: Most dev tools has a JS prettifier installed, on Chrome it's a popup on bottom left corner of the code editor. You can't magically puzzle it all together, though, no.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the source map is available for the bundled JavaScript, that is not possible. But in general, in production, source maps are either disabled and hidden behind a debug mode which is enabled only when production issue needs to be debugged in some rare situations. If there is a source-map (generally the bundle name + `.map` file example, for `build.js`, it would be `build.js.map`), the Dev Tool should pick it up provided they are enabled in the Dev Tools.

There is a prettifier in the Dev Tools but it is generally useless most of the variables, symbols are renamed/mangled and shortened to reduce payload size. Prettifier cannot restore original name.

So, there is not solid way to do this.